# Oracle unique constraint error ORA 0001

Tags: database, oracle, pentaho

Hi I am using pentaho to insert some values from one DB to another DB. In my source I have an attribute which is the primary key of that table. At my destination I have the same attribute as a unique constraint. But still I get a ORA-00001: unique constraint violated error while inserting. I am not sure why this is can anyone help ?

```
Source:
table
( 
empid(PK),
empname
)

Destination:
 table1
 (
 empgroupid(PK)
 empid(unique)
 )
```

source to destination error: ORA-00001: unique constraint violated

Comment: . . The logical conclusion is that a row with the same `empid` already exists in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You likely don't want "table1"."empid" to be unique; you probably want it to be a foreign key to "table"."empid". Especially if an employee can be in more than one group at once.